# Importrange and Query Issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

What started as a pretty simple project has now gotten a bit over my head and I could really use a point in the right direction.  I have two issues within this group of sheets and will include links below.  I have a report being populated with two sets of data.

**Problem 1:**  Trying to populate a cell in the "Marketing Update Sheet" with a count in "Showing Traffic- apptmanage" if two criteria are met.  If column C matches a unique identifier number in cell E5 and if column A is after the date in E9.

**Problem 2:**  I have data populating from "Marketing" sheet in B28 of the "Marketing Update Sheet"  I now need to add the stipulation that the date in column 1 needs to be after the same date in cell E9.

Thank you for any guidance you can provide!

Main Sheet - "Marketing Update"
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RIORAKgdc4EJiT4xFeQFmzs00c9de3bXKRCtF2TU1Do/edit?usp=sharing

Showing Traffic Sheet
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qnyn2dF8Hu7l16Cs3wRvmG8TJ8fkxm2Quqtnd9vWKCw/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13lr2oeOrVsZNpJU-lkJcx-sNaDyHDZGO1CV4KQnLddo/edit?usp=sharing)

Marketing Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MepPU0oH6Hr4VFpeFgJiYojKYAdAL1SzfLzlOGW7yDk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### problem 1:

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1Qnyn2dF8Hu7l16Cs3wRvmG8TJ8fkxm2Quqtnd9vWKCw", 
 "apptmanage!A7:C20000"),
 "SELECT Col3 WHERE Col1 > date '"&TEXT(E9,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  and (Col3 matches '"&E5&"' or Col3 matches '"&J5&"')"))
```

[image: 5]

---

### problem 2:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1AQUb2VcyrmpnoXztBxRMAu4z0npBEj6zPgr4BbBzuL0","advertising!A:G"), 
 INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("1AQUb2VcyrmpnoXztBxRMAu4z0npBEj6zPgr4BbBzuL0","advertising!A:G"),0,4)=E4),
 "where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(E9, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is fantastic!!  Thank you for your help! The solution to problem 2 works perfectly!  The solution to problem 1 is returning a result of 1 when a direct countifs on the data within the sheet returns 6.  See cell C610 in the Showing Traffic Sheet.  Do I have the formatting incorrect?

Comment: You are amazing!  I can't thank you enough for your help!